# check if user have account or not when application start

Tags: android

i used to make launcher activity which contain app logo and sleep for 2 seconds and then check if user have

account go to main activity if not go to sign up/in activity

i wander if i could done this step without launcher activity ?

is it correct to use code like this :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (HaveAccount())
    setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);
    else
    setContentView(R.layout.Auth);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a separate launcher activity, MainActivity, and Auth activity.  You would then place the logic in your splash activity after determining the user's status.  So in the Launcher activity you would have logic after the 2 seconds saying

```
if (hasAccount()) { 
    startActivity(this, MainActivity.class); 
} else { 
    startActivity(this, AuthActivity.class); 
}
```

In the MainActivity.onCreate() you would place the setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity) & in the AuthActivity.onCreate() you would place the setContentView(R.layout.AuthActivity).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to enter the application through the launcher Activity.

One the app did it you can
A) open a new activity for sign up/in --or--
B) work with fragments